# How to combine two ObservableCollection to bind dynamic buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

This is using C# and MVVM.

At the moment I have a bunch of buttons that are created on to a panel via binding an ObservableCollection<Module> called ModuleCollection.

module is defined as:

```
public string ModuleName { get; private set; }
public string ModuleAbbreviation { get; private set; }
public bool ModuleDisabled { get; private set; }
public DateTime ModuleLicenseDate { get; private set; }
```

A label below each button gets set to ModuleName and the Content property of the button gets set to ModuleAbbreviation.

I also have a current_user object that holds a ObservableCollection<UserModule> called UserModules
A UserModule is defined as:

```
public int Module_ID { get; set; }
public int User_Module_Access { get; set; }
```

Using the ModuleCollection and current_user.UserModules lists, I would like to enable the buttons under the follow scenarios:

- If the Module.Disabled = false
- and the Module.ModuleLicenseDate > Now()
- and the UserModule.User_Module_Access > 0

Otherwise the button will be disabled.

Other things to note: is that UserModules may only have a subset of ModuleCollection and ModuleCollection will be static but the properties within UserModules will be refreshed from time to time.

My question is: How to I go about binding these two collections so that I can them create my buttons and set the IsEnabled property based on both?

**[EDIT] 2013-12-07**

```
<Button.IsEnabled>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{Binding viewmodel:IsEnabledMultiValueConverter}">
        <Binding Source="{Binding ModuleID}" />
        <Binding Source="{Binding ModuleDisabled}" />
        <Binding Source="{Binding ModuleLicenseDate}" />
        <Binding Source="{Binding current_user.user_modules}" />
    </MultiBinding>
</Button.IsEnabled>
```

**[EDIT2] 2013-12-09**

When I change the module access level in a user module the event is getting fired. I change the value from accessible(1) to unaccessible(0), so in-turn the button should get disabled, however this does not happen.

```
public class UserModule : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public UserModule(int Module_ID, int User_Module_Access)
    {
        this.Module_ID = Module_ID;
        this.User_Module_Access = User_Module_Access;
    }

    private int _userModuleAccess;

    public int Module_ID { get; set; }

    public int User_Module_Access
    {
        get { return _userModuleAccess; }
        set
        {
            _userModuleAccess = value;
            MessageBox.Show("User_Module_Access");
            RaisePropertyChanged("User_Module_Access");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    }
}
```

My thoughts are, that an event for ObservableCollection<UserModule> needs to occur when an item property changes. I have read that ObservableCollections don't do this, only adding, deleting and moving items. How to do this?

Some how in the User class?

```
public class User
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<UserModule> UserModules = new ObservableCollection<UserModule>();
}
```

**[Edit3] 2013-12-10 Redo - Implementing ItemsObservableObservableCollection**
Launcher.XAML

```
<Button Content="{Binding ModuleAbbreviation}" 
        Style="{DynamicResource LauncherButton}"
        Background="{Binding ModuleColor}" 
        FontSize="32" FontFamily="Tahoma" Width="130" Height="100" 
        Command="{Binding DataContext.LaunchCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding ModuleName}">
    <Button.Resources>
        <viewmodel:IsEnabledMultiValueConverter x:Key="converter" />
    </Button.Resources>
    <Button.IsEnabled>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource converter}">
            <Binding Path="ModuleID" />
            <Binding Path="ModuleEnabled" />
            <Binding Path="ModuleLicenseDate" />
            <Binding ElementName="gridModules" Path="DataContext.CurrentUser" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Button.IsEnabled>
</Button>
```

LauncherViewModel.cs

```
class LauncherViewModel
{
    public LauncherViewModel()
    {
        timer = new Timer(SetModuleAccess, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    }
    int pass = 0;
    bool _isEnabled = false;
    Timer timer;
    private void SetModuleAccess(object state)
    {
        if (pass > 0)
        {
            if (_isEnabled)
                _isEnabled = false;
            else
                _isEnabled = true;

            foreach (Users.UserModule uModule in ups.model.ups_repository._current_user.UserModules)
            {
                if (uModule.Module_ID == 0)
                {
                    if (_isEnabled == false)
                        uModule.User_Module_Access = 0;
                    else
                        uModule.User_Module_Access = 1;
                }
            }
            if (pass == 2)
                ups.model.ups_repository._current_user.UserModules.Add(new Users.UserModule(8, 1));
        }
        pass++;
    }

    public Users.User CurrentUser
    {
        get { return ups.model.ups_repository._current_user; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Module> ModuleCollection
    {
        get { return ModuleKey._module_objects; }
    }
}
public class IsEnabledMultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            bool userHasAccess = false;
            int ModuleID = (int)values[0];
            bool ModuleEnabled = (bool)values[1];
            string ModuleLicenseDate = (string)values[2];

            Users.User user = values[3] as Users.User;
            Users.UserModule userModule = user.UserModules.SingleOrDefault(um => um.Module_ID == ModuleID);

            DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
            dtfi.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
            dtfi.DateSeparator = "-";
            DateTime MLicenseDate = System.Convert.ToDateTime(ModuleLicenseDate, dtfi);

            if (userModule != null)
            {
                userHasAccess = userModule.User_Module_Access > 0;
            }
            return (ModuleEnabled && (MLicenseDate >= DateTime.Now) && userHasAccess);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

User.cs

```
public class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static User CreateNewUser()
    {
        return new User();
    }

    public User() {}

    public int User_ID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Job_Title { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Phone_Office { get; set; }
    public string Phone_Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime Last_Login { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public int Session_Timeout { get; set; }

    private ItemsObservableObservableCollection<UserModule> user_modules = new ItemsObservableObservableCollection<UserModule>();

    public ItemsObservableObservableCollection<UserModule> UserModules
    {
        get
        {
            return user_modules;
        }
        set
        {
            user_modules = value;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    }
}
```

UserModule.cs

```
public class UserModule : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public UserModule(int Module_ID)
    {
        this.Module_ID = Module_ID;
    }

    public UserModule(int Module_ID, int User_Module_Access)
    {
        this.Module_ID = Module_ID;
        this.User_Module_Access = User_Module_Access;
    }

    private int _module_id;
    private int _userModuleAccess;

    public int Module_ID
    {
        get { return _module_id; }
        set
        {
            _module_id = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Module_ID");
        }
    }

    public int User_Module_Access
    {
        get { return _userModuleAccess; }
        set
        {
            _userModuleAccess = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("User_Module_Access");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    }
}
```

ups.cs

```
namespace ups.model
{
    public static class ups_repository
    {
        public static Users.User _current_user = new Users.User();

        public static void LoadUser(string Username, string Key, string Message)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

At this point buttons are displaying, in the VM above I switch the first user module in the collection from enabled to disabled, each five seconds. I also add permission for the last in the collection. The buttons are not enabled and disabling the way they should.

Comment: Plese see below "Implementing ItemsObservableObservableCollection" if the custom observable collection class helps to overcome the problem that the collection is not listening to changes of the contained objects.

Comment: I think, I got it. User.user_modules is a field. Please try by changing it to Property.

Comment: I thought you are using User object as DataContext, so, suggested to make the user_modules as property in the User class. Exactly what is the issue you are facing? Are you able to see the buttons created on the UI? What is the DataContext is it User or UserModules collection? To what control you are binding the DataContext?

Comment: Sorry I been trying all sorts of things to get this to work. I have now reset things to the way they were. I deleted [EDIT4] and refreshed the code in [EDIT3] and added notes.

Comment: It should be on the way

Comment: Launcher.xaml <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ModuleCollection}" >; LauncherViewModel.cs public ObservableCollection<Module> ModuleCollection; ModuleKey.cs _module_objects = new ObservableCollection<Module>(); All the involved collections are ObservableCollections. Please use ItemsObservableObservableCollection at all these places. The problem is you bound the ModuleCollection which is an ObservableCollection and which cannot recognize the property changes of the contained items. So, changing the property of an item in this collection does not make any change on the UI.

Comment: I understand, I have altered two spots, in ModuleKey.cs and LauncherViewModel.cs where they were ObservableCollection and changed them to ItemsObservableObservableCollection. Enabling and disabling buttons via property change remain unresponsive. Is there something I need to add on the properties within User and ModuleKey to pick up CollectionChanged perhaps?

Comment: I sent you the solution in mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try MultiBinding with MultiValueConverter on IsEnabled property of Button. The MultiValueConverter will take the Module bound to the Button; and the Module Collection of the current user (in the following example I sent the user itself) and do the testing to return a bool to indicate if the Button can be enabled or disabled.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfHowTo.ItemsControlTestHorn"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:WpfHowTo"
        Title="ItemsControlTestHorn" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <l:MultiValueConverter x:Key="multiValueConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Name="gridModules">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Modules}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Button Content="{Binding ModuleAbbreviation}">
                            <Button.IsEnabled>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multiValueConverter}">
                                    <Binding Path="."/>
                                    <Binding ElementName="gridModules" Path="DataContext.CurrentUser"/>
                                    <!--<Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}" Path="DataContext.CurrentUser"/>-->
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Button.IsEnabled>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl> 
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The MultiValueConverter is something like this.

```
public class MultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool result = true;

        Module module = values[0] as Module;
        User user = values[1] as User;
        bool userHasAccess = false;

        UserModule userModule = user.UserModules.SingleOrDefault(um => um.Module_ID == module.Module_ID);

        if (userModule != null)
        {
            userHasAccess = userModule.User_Module_Access == 1;
        }

        return result = ! module.ModuleDisabled && module.ModuleLicenseDate > DateTime.Now && userHasAccess;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Class definitions

```
public class Module
{
    public int Module_ID { get; set; }
    public string ModuleName { get; set; }
    public string ModuleAbbreviation { get; set; }
    public bool ModuleDisabled { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModuleLicenseDate { get; set; }
}

public class UserModule
{
    public int Module_ID { get; set; }
    public int User_Module_Access { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    private ObservableCollection<UserModule> _userModules = new ObservableCollection<UserModule>();
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<UserModule> UserModules
    {
        get
        {
            return _userModules;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am unsure of one thing. Getting the ModuleDisabled and ModuleLicenseDate in the MultiBinding is easy enough as I am already in that context. However, how would I add the third binding, module from the current user? Wouldn't I need to match [Module from Module-Button] to [Module from current user]? If yes how can I do that?  Or am I just giving it the whole [Module Collection of the current user]

Comment: Just added possible example above, is this what you mean?

Comment: I have added a PropertyChangedEventHandler to User_Module_Access in the UserModule class. This is firing just fine, however and correct me if I'm wrong, but because I bind the current user (I also successfully bound the user module collection as well), not the individual user module. The binding does not notice the change. Somehow I'd need to bubble up the event to either the user module collection or current user level. Could you through a little light on this for me?

Comment: @Hank I am not sure if I got you correctly. It would be helpful if you provide the code that you are trying with.

Comment: Added further comments above, see [EDIT2]

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with one more idea which is more simpler. However, I am leaving the first answer as an example for MultiBinding.

Here goes the new idea. I have created a new collection using the other two collections. This technique is now in line with the title of the question.

```
public IEnumerable<object> Modules
{
    get
    {
        ObservableCollection<Module> modules = GetAllModules();
        User currentUser = GetCurrentUser();

        var accessibleModules = modules.GroupJoin
            (
                currentUser.UserModules, m => m.Module_ID, um => um.Module_ID,
                (m, um) => new
                {
                    ModuleName = m.ModuleName,
                    ModuleAbbreviation = m.ModuleAbbreviation,
                    IsModuleAccessible = !m.ModuleDisabled && m.ModuleLicenseDate > DateTime.Now && (um.Count() == 0 ? -1 : um.Single().User_Module_Access) == 1
                }
            );

        return accessibleModules;
    }
}
```

In the .xaml

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Modules}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Button Content="{Binding ModuleAbbreviation}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsModuleAccessible}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: This is great I was wondering if something this this was possible.

Answer (score 1):

## ItemsObservableObservableCollection

The following class is intended to overcome the problem that ObservableCollection does not listen to the changes of the contained objects.

The pre-requisite is that the objects which are being added to this collection should implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

In short, this class registers to the items' PropertyChanged event and rises the CollectionChanged event of the ObservableCollection.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd252944.aspx

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Collections;

namespace VJ.Collections
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     This class adds the ability to refresh the list when any property of
    ///     the objects changes in the list which implements the INotifyPropertyChanged. 
    ///
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">
    ///     The type of elements in the collection.
    /// </typeparam>
    public class ItemsObservableObsrvableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            {
                RegisterPropertyChanged(e.NewItems);
            }
            else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
            {
                UnRegisterPropertyChanged(e.OldItems);
            }
            else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
            {
                UnRegisterPropertyChanged(e.OldItems);
                RegisterPropertyChanged(e.NewItems);
            }

            base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
        }

        protected override void ClearItems()
        {
            UnRegisterPropertyChanged(this);
            base.ClearItems();
        }

        private void RegisterPropertyChanged(IList items)
        {
            foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged item in items)
            {
                item.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
            }
        }

        private void UnRegisterPropertyChanged(IList items)
        {
            foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged item in items)
            {
                item.PropertyChanged -= new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
            }
        }

        private void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The collection as far as enabling/disabling buttons is unresponsive. I have placed everything as far as code goes in EDIT3

Comment: @Hank Please try the updated ItemsObservableObservableCollection.

Comment: I have swapped out the old for the new, updating user module remains unresponsive.

Comment: I think the User.user_modules is a field and so the binding is not working. Try by changing it to a Property. BTW, I have more refined the ItemsObservableObservableCollection. Please use this.

Comment: You may like this. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/64936/Multi-Threaded-ObservableCollection-and-NotifyColl